# JQUERY pass value from link and return it or forward it

Tags: jquery

I am trying to:

click on the link shown below and have the value passed to an JQUERY $.get (I think it has to be done like that) and this should be made available to a SQL snippet which will include it its WHERE clause.

LINK

```
$sOutput .= '"<a href=\"#whatever?' .addslashes($aRow['id_cruise']) .'\" class=\"flip\">'.addslashes($aRow['from_country']).'</a>",';
```

When I click on the link, you see that Flip class. That does open alright a slide pannel within which I have a div that would be populated after a SQL query works with the value sent:

JQUERY SNIPPET

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a.flip').live('click',function(){
    $(".panel").slideToggle("slow");

  });
});
</script>
```

As you can see, it uses the LIVE function so that up on clicking indeed activates the slide pannel open. But I need that last bit more, the one that sends the value (of id_cruise). When I hover down the rows, I can see that the value of ID changes, which is great, but however I am not getting to make it passed to the snippet and picked up by the SQL query.

So I can see that in the link, where I write "whatever", indeed it doesnt matter, as long as it has the # sign. Note that the Link is part of the server processing file, whilst the JQUERY is on the user visible page file, they are in two different pages.

UPDATED FROM HERE, INCLUDING NOW THE CODE FROM JEFF:

The link looks so now:

```
$sOutput .= '"<a href=\"#id?' .addslashes($aRow['id_cruise']) .'\" class=\"flip\">'.addslashes($aRow['from_country']).'</a>",';
```

Jeff wisely indicated how there should be a third file which would get the parameter from the second JQUERY snippet, return it and this second would pass it to a third one located just below. This third snippet is the one that forwards it to the DIV box located inside the slide panel.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

$(document).ready(function(){
$('a.flip').live('click',function(){
$(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
      DoSomethingWith(this.id);

     });

});
</script>


 <script type="text/javascript">

function DoSomethingWith(id) {
  $.get("SendIdToDatabase.php", {idCruise: id}, AnotherFunction);
}
function AnotherFunction(str) {
  $("#reviews").html(str);
}
</script>
```

OTHER CONTRIBUTOR SAID THAT IT COULD BE MERGED AND SIMPLIFIED INTO THIS:

```
$(function() {
      $('a.flip').live('click',function() {
            $('.panel').slideToggle(slow');
            $('#reviews').load('SendIdToDatabase.php', {idCruise: this.id});
      });
});
```

SO NOW I CREATE THE PHP CODE (SendIdToDatabase.php) THAT WILL HANDLE THE SQL REQUEST

```
 <?php


$id_crucero = $_REQUEST['id_cruise']; //this is what I (hopefully) should get from the page
              require ('mysqli_connect.php');

                    $sql ="SELECT description
                        FROM cruises
                        WHERE id_cruise
                        = '".$id_crucero."'";

                        $result = @mysql_query ($sql);

                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {


                    $reviews = ($row['description']);
                    echo "$reviews";
                    }        

                      ?>
```

AND FROM HERE IT SHOULD ECHO IT TO THE SECOND AJAX CODE SNIPPET WHICH FORWARDS IT TO THE PANEL (WHICH I HAVE RENAMED TO "REVIEWS" AND IT IS A DIV, NOT AN HTML)

BUT SOME LINK MUST BE BUGGY AS AT SOME POINT THE VALUE IS NOT PASSED OR RECEIVED.

AS OF 1 DECEMBER THE VALUE IS STILL NOT PASSED ON. I HARDCODED SOME TEXT IN THE PHP SCRIPT AND YES, THAT IS SHOWN IN THE DIV BOX INSIDE THE PANEL BUT IT DOES NOT SHOW THE VALUE

Comment: Where exactly do you call the $.get?

Comment: well that is supposed to forward the value of id into the sql php script that queries the db. There is an alternative code proposed to that seems more simplified, yet I am not sure either. It directly loads the content of the echoed data from the php script into the DIV box that is in the panel. I dont see however in that simplifed code at which moment the id value was sent to the SendIdToDatabase.php file. There must be a very little thing but it is boycotting the passing.

Comment: I am suspecting it is the # sign there. In that a href I should be able to place the full name of the page to where I can link, but I cant because I am working with dreamweaver and everytime I upload the page it brings up a temporary number like 234w234323234.php that is why I have to put the # so that it does not open a new page and stays where it is, but I dont know if by placing that # the values dont get passed on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is the "this" object. Within the "this" object, you can get the id property. For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a.flip').live('click',function(){
    $(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
    DoSomethingWith(this.id);
  });
});
</script>
```

Once you have the id, you can then pass it to another script with Ajax for processing:
For Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function DoSomethingWith(id) {
  $.get("SendIdToDatabase.php", {idCruise: id}, AnotherFunction);
}
function AnotherFunction(str) {
  $(".panel").html(str);
}
</script>
```

Check out [jQuery Get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) for documentation on sending "get" Ajax calls.

You would need to write the php script (SendIdToDatabase.php) to do whatever you wanted with the id. Don't forget to remove the #Whatever, from the id before using it.

As for why it needs to be a separate script, you need to understand the "disconnected" nature of http requests. [Here](http://www.cristiandarie.ro/asp-ajax/Quickstart.html) [are](http://www.ajaxtutorial.net/index.php/category/ajax-basics/) [some](http://www.modelworks.com/ajax.html) decent explanations and diagrams.

Comment: Hello,

Thank you very much for the time dedicated. The PHP script to which you are referring you mean for including the SQL query ? If yes, I am including that PHP snippet inside the DIV panel which is what slides open and close upon clicking on the link. For the rest, do I just take your code AS IS, or was it a pseudocode?. As per the Alert, well I ll have to do without that. I am on the GET documentation for JQUERY for more than one hour and it is how I am trying to do it.  Thank you again

Comment: The target PHP script would have to be a new script. Once a page is rendered the original PHP script ceases to run, it does not see any of the data that happens client side. This is exactly the sort of problem Ajax is trying to solve. But it does need to be a separate script. You can't have server-side code aware of what happens client side.

Comment: The code will work as is, but you might want to change some of the names to something that makes more sense with your application. Also, the return function might not be necessary. Again, I don't know what you are trying to do with the data.

Comment: Hello,

Tnx U much for the time dedicated. Questions: If I write that php script for the DB, I still need that the results be shown INSIDE the slide panel. So, would I then need another snippet from the DIV panel to load or import the displays from the sendToDatabase.php file? and, what you have written as code, is it valid AS IS? thanks a lot

Comment: I edited the "AnotherFunction" to send the results to the panel. I believe that is what you are looking for. This will work as is. Again, you might want to change the names of things, but you don't have to.

Comment: Thank you very much for your insightful and helpful comment, I ll try to work from there. Best regards, Alvaro

Comment: Jeff, If I remove the # from the link, the slide panel won't work, it won't slide open. Dont ask me why but it is so.

Comment: It's because the anchor "#" on a tag will make it so it doesn't load a new page. Instead of putting the id inside "href" you can put it inside "id" IE: $sOutput .= '"<a id=\"' .addslashes($aRow['id_cruise']) .'\" class=\"flip\">'.addslashes($aRow['from_country']).'</a>",';

Comment: You will need to use css to make it still act correctly like a link however.

Comment: Hmm, yes, the link still opens the panel like that, but the cursor does not turn into a finger anymore. It may be a bit confusing for the user. I still have to investigate why i am not getting the panel populated. I will review all steps.

Comment: I think I can safely leave the link like this

    $sOutput .= '"<a href=\"#id?' .addslashes($aRow['id_cruise']) .'\" class=\"flip\">'.addslashes($aRow['from_country']).'</a>",';

Comment: The firebug extension in firefox (the Net tab) can be very helpful for investigating what is happening behind the scenes.

Comment: Firebug gave 200 OK for SendIdToDatabase. I have updated the full code above, including the brief PHP code

Comment: 2 tweaks: In your php script you need to echo $reviews. So literally add "echo $reviews;"

Comment: Also DoSomethingWith(this.id); needs to be inside the click function. So move the DoSomethingWith line up 2 lines so it comes after $(".panel").slideToggle("slow"); but before });

Comment: Edited it. What is this exactly ? $(".panel").html(str); because it reads html and actually where it should be a div, it is a DIV box inside the panel which gets the description content. But shouldnt there be some kind of anchor inside the DIV that picks the content sent from the JQUERY ? otherwise it looks like is thrown in without specifying where, because the DIV box does have a header with another background.

Comment: Yes, you would want to specify the target rather than just the whole panel, if you have one. So for example, if the id of the div you want to change is "target" you would want it to be $("#target").html(str); the html() function changes the contents of whatever you specify as a target inside $()

Comment: I included in the edition a simplified piece of code where the DIV actually loads the content from the PHP script instead of having it bounced from the GET. I am still though not getting the value passed. I am flummoxed.

Comment: Well, the problem IS in the link. I am not sending any ID value in here: 

    $sOutput .= '"<a href=\"#id' .addslashes($aRow['id_cruise']) .'\" class=\"flip\">'.addslashes($aRow['from_country']).'</a>",';

Comment: Try this: $sOutput .= '"<a href=\"#\" id=\"id' .addslashes($aRow['id_cruise']) .'\" class=\"flip\">'.addslashes($aRow['from_country']).'</a>",';

Comment: Thank you Jeff.Your code was fantastic. I posted after that the issue I had with a link and that was solved too. Then someone else posted an alternative which is shorter and also works but it was very insightful for me to see how JQUERY needs to be written, hope I have time to learn it since I am doing a huge web myself alone and have to learn everything on the go, from AJAX to rounding the corners of the boxes. Thank you again, excellent job!